# Bind Kendo Grid using Linq to EF query in MVC 5

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-grid

Here goes.  I'm new to MVC and EF trying to build my first project that will allow batch edits of corporate credit card transactions.  Kendo Grid seems to be the best method to get this done.

The query takes two parameters that are passed in the querystring (accountID and statement date).  I've been able to bind the grid to a model and have it display correct transactions.  Next, I need to configure it to do the batch edits.  I'm stuck at this step.
Currently two issues:

1. Cannot get grid to bind to the Transaction_Read method (returns empty grid).  The index method will work to bind transactions to grid but not in Json.
2. Cannot get grid to do a batch update. It will get all the way to .SaveChanges function but doesn't actually update any fields.

My model:

```
namespace intranetMVC.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public partial class CorpCardTransaction
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime ImportDate { get; set; }
    public string AccountID { get; set; }
    public string CardHolderName { get; set; }
    //[DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> StatementDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> StatementRecordNum { get; set; }        
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> PostDate { get; set; }        
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> TranDate { get; set; }
    public string Payee { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Amount { get; set; }
    public string GL_Account { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> BranchCode { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Receipt { get; set; }        
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> BackDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> SubmitDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ProcessDate { get; set; }
    public string MemberNum { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
}
```

CorpCardTransactionsController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using intranetMVC.Models;
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;

namespace intranetMVC.Controllers
{
public class CorpCardTransactionsController : Controller
{
    private ExpenseReportingEntities db = new ExpenseReportingEntities();       

    public ActionResult Index(string AccountID, DateTime StatementDate)
    {
        //var loginName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\');
        //var username = loginName.Last() + "@xxxx.com";
        var username = "xxxx@xxxx.com";
        var stmtDate = StatementDate;
        var q = from b in db.CorpCardTransactions
                where b.Username == username && b.StatementDate == StatementDate && b.AccountID == AccountID && !b.SubmitDate.HasValue
                select b;
        return View(q.ToList());            
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Transaction_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string AccountID, DateTime StatementDate)
    {
        //var loginName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\');
        //var username = loginName.Last() + "@xxxx.com";
        var username = "xxxx@xxxx.com";
        var stmtDate = StatementDate;
        var q = from b in db.CorpCardTransactions
                where b.Username == username && b.StatementDate == StatementDate && b.AccountID == AccountID && !b.SubmitDate.HasValue
                select b;            
        return View(q.ToList());
        //IQueryable<CorpCardTransaction> transactions = q.ToList();
        //DataSourceResult result = transactions.ToDataSourceResult(result);
        //return Json(result);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Transaction_Update([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<CorpCardTransaction> corpCardTransaction)
    {

        var entities = new List<CorpCardTransaction>();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (db)
            {
                foreach (var transaction in corpCardTransaction)
                {
                    var entity = new CorpCardTransaction
                    {
                        ID = transaction.ID,
                        Description = transaction.Description,
                        GL_Account = transaction.GL_Account,
                        BranchCode = transaction.BranchCode,
                        Receipt = transaction.Receipt
                    };
                    entities.Add(entity);
                    db.CorpCardTransactions.Attach(entity);
                    db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        return Json(entities.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState, transaction => new CorpCardTransaction
        {
            ID = transaction.ID,
            Description = transaction.Description,
            GL_Account = transaction.GL_Account,
            BranchCode = transaction.BranchCode,
            Receipt = transaction.Receipt
        }));
    }
}
```

}

index.cshtml View

```
@*@model IEnumerable<intranetMVC.Models.CorpCardTransaction>*@

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Corporate Card Transactions</h2>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<intranetMVC.Models.CorpCardTransaction>()>
.Name("gvTransactions")    
.Columns(columns => 
{
    columns.Bound(c => c.ID);
    columns.Bound(c => c.AccountID);
    columns.Bound(c => c.CardHolderName);
    columns.Bound(c => c.StatementDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
    columns.Bound(c => c.PostDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
    columns.Bound(c => c.TranDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
    columns.Bound(c => c.Payee);
    columns.Bound(c => c.Amount);
    columns.Bound(c => c.Description);
    columns.Bound(c => c.GL_Account);
    columns.Bound(c => c.BranchCode);
    columns.Bound(c => c.Receipt);
})
    .ToolBar(toolBar => 
    {
        toolBar.Save();                      
    })        
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Batch(true)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))            
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(c => c.ID);
            model.Field(c => c.AccountID).Editable(false);
            model.Field(c => c.CardHolderName).Editable(false);
            model.Field(c => c.StatementDate).Editable(false);
            model.Field(c => c.PostDate).Editable(false);
            model.Field(c => c.TranDate).Editable(false);
            model.Field(c => c.Payee).Editable(false);
            model.Field(c => c.Amount).Editable(false);
        })
          .Read("Transaction_Read", "CorpCardTransactions")
          .Update("Transaction_Update", "CorpCardTransactions")            
    )
)
<script type="text/javascript">
function error_handler(e) {
    if (e.errors) {
        var message = "Errors:\n";
        $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
            if ('errors' in value) {
                $.each(value.errors, function() {
                    message += this + "\n";
                });
            }
        });
        alert(message);
    }
}
```

Am I binding the grid correctly here in the View?

I've googled as many different ways as possible and haven't found the answer to what I'm trying to do.  I don't think my update function is working because the grid isn't bound initially with Json results.  Not sure how to return my Linq to EF query as Json to the grid.  And after that, seems like there should be an easier way to do the batch updates.

Comment: I would throw Kendo out the window and use mustache. ASP.NET MVC and javascript rocks :) And you'll get full control.

Comment: you need to pass the model to the grid @(Html.Kendo().Grid<intranetMVC.Models.CorpCardTransaction>(Model)> and your Transaction_Read return type is wrong. supposed to return result.ToDataSourceResult(request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Transaction_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string AccountID, DateTime StatementDate)
    {
        //var loginName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\');
        //var username = loginName.Last() + "@xxxx.com";
        var username = "xxxx@xxxx.com";
        var stmtDate = StatementDate;
        var q = from b in db.CorpCardTransactions
                where b.Username == username && b.StatementDate == StatementDate && b.AccountID == AccountID && !b.SubmitDate.HasValue
                select b;            
        return Json(q.ToList().ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }
```

For update, check if there is any error at `if (ModelState.IsValid) { .... }`

Replace your `uysing (db)` block with below code (I did not test this code)

```
using (db)
            {
                foreach (var transaction in corpCardTransaction)
                {
                    var entity = new CorpCardTransaction
                    {
                        ID = transaction.ID,
                        Description = transaction.Description,
                        GL_Account = transaction.GL_Account,
                        BranchCode = transaction.BranchCode,
                        Receipt = transaction.Receipt
                    };
                    db.CorpCardTransactions.Add(entity);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks HaBo.  I changed my grid statement in the view to this: `@(Html.Kendo().Grid<intranetMVC.Models.CorpCardTransaction>(Model)`, but then I get the following error: `CS1977: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type`, and if I remove Model from the parense it'll display the grid without any data and no errors.

Comment: There are no errors with the `if (ModelState.IsValid)` it actually runs all the way to the `db.SaveChanges();` function with all the correct variable values, but no changes are made to the database.  No errors are thrown.  Any ideas on how to troubleshoot that?  Does my Transaction_Update ActionResult look okay?

Comment: No it is not. In Entity Framework you have to do one record add/update at a time. updated my answer for update

Comment: Thank you!!!! That makes total sense and it works!!!  I really appreciate your time HaBo, answer marked accordingly.

Comment: Update: it's actually making it past the db.savechanges() function, and it's persisting in the grid which it didn't do before, but it's not actually writing back to the database :(  Thoughts?  I'm thinking EF should just take care of this correct?

Comment: Make sure you are looking in right database. And Grid will persist the data, that is Kendo default behaviour. put a try catch to db.SaveChanges() and see if it throws any error if not, then next thing you can try is if you have SQL profiler you can see the SQL script that is being generated by the entity framework command